# Bresenham's Line Algorithm implementation in SQL (find cells which intersects with line)

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql, bresenham

I have coordinates data in SQL tables (Postgres DB). There are two tables in DB:

- "Line" table which contains GID, XStart, XEnd, YStart, YEnd
- "Matrix" table which contains CellID, X and Y of cell start. Constant of cell size is 1, so if cell starts at 5,4, so it will end in 6,5.

I need to find all Matrix CellID which intersects with specific line. F.E.

```
select matrix.CellID
from line, matrix 
where line.gid = 1 and ???
```

Comment: Bresenham's alorithm is for interpolating or drawing lines. There is a very simple formula for checking if to lines intersect. You can write a function which does this check for two lines. A cell consists of 4 lines. Thus your query should test the line with all four sides of a cell.

Comment: Thanks for response! I probably made a mistake in my local code due to cell sizes. 
Because as you told my first solution which is probably correct was something like:
where gid = 1 and (    
    GREATEST(XStart,XEnd)<=X+1 and
    LEAST(XStart,XEnd)>=X and
    GREATEST(YStart,YEnd)<=Y+1 and
    LEAST(YStart,YEnd)>=Y
        )